# System.IO.FileNotFoundException generating OpenAPI Specifications File in ASP.NET Core when deploying to Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to deploy my API to Azure App Service via Github Actions but i receive this error when generating the OpenAPI specifications document.

Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: .\bin\Release\net6.0\EDP-Backend.dll

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: .\bin\Release\net6.0\EDP-Backend.dll
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Main>b__2(IDictionary`2 namedArgs) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\Program.cs:line 43
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.CommandRunner.Run(IEnumerable`1 args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\CommandRunner.cs:line 68
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.CommandRunner.Run(IEnumerable`1 args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\CommandRunner.cs:line 68
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\Program.cs:line 111
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQzYu.png)

Here is my current swagger configuration used:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    var securityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Token",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        Scheme = "Bearer",
        Reference = new OpenApiReference
        {
            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
            Id = "Bearer"
        }
    };
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", securityScheme);
    options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
    { securityScheme, new List<string>() }
    });

    options.EnableAnnotations();
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "EDP_Backend", Version = "v1" });
});
```

```cs
app.UseSwagger();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

Lastly the deployment YML file used to build and deploy the project using github actions.

```yaml
name: Build and deploy .NET Core application to Web App EDP-Backend with API Management Service EDP-Backendapi-EDP-Backend
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master
env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: EDP-Backend
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: .\publish
  AZURE_APIM_RESOURCE_PATH: /
  AZURE_APIM_RESOURCEGROUP: edpbackend
  AZURE_APIM_SERVICENAME: EDP-Backendapi
  AZURE_APIM_API_ID: EDP-Backend
  AZURE_APIM_APPSERVICEURL: https://edp-backend.azurewebsites.net
  SWASHBUCLE_ASPNET_CORE_CLI_PACKAGE_VERSION: 5.6.3
  SWASHBUCKLE_DOTNET_CORE_VERSION: 3.1.x
  API_IMPORT_SPECIFICATION_PATH: .\publish\swagger.json
  API_IMPORT_DLL: .\bin\Release\net6.0\EDP-Backend.dll
  API_IMPORT_VERSION: v1
  CONFIGURATION: Release
  DOTNET_CORE_VERSION: 6.0.x
  WORKING_DIRECTORY: .
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup .NET SDK
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_CORE_VERSION }}
    - name: Setup SwashBuckle .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ env.SWASHBUCKLE_DOTNET_CORE_VERSION }}
    - name: Restore
      run: dotnet restore ${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build ${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }} --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-restore
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test ${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }} --no-build
    - name: Publish
      run: dotnet publish ${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }} --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-build --output ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
    - name: Install Swashbuckle CLI .NET Global Tool
      run: dotnet tool install --global Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli --version ${{ env.SWASHBUCLE_ASPNET_CORE_CLI_PACKAGE_VERSION }}
      working-directory: ${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}
    - name: Generate Open API Specification Document
      run: swagger tofile --output "${{ env.API_IMPORT_SPECIFICATION_PATH }}" "${{ env.API_IMPORT_DLL }}" "${{ env.API_IMPORT_VERSION }}"
    - name: Publish Artifacts
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: webapp
        path: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
    - name: Download artifact from build job
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: webapp
        path: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
    - name: Deploy to Azure WebApp
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
        package: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.EDP_Backend_685C }}
    - name: Azure Login
      uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.EDP_Backendapi_SPN }}
    - name: Import API into Azure API Management
      run: az apim api import --path "${{ env.AZURE_APIM_RESOURCE_PATH }}" --resource-group "${{ env.AZURE_APIM_RESOURCEGROUP }}" --service-name "${{ env.AZURE_APIM_SERVICENAME }}" --api-id "${{ env.AZURE_APIM_API_ID }}" --service-url "${{ env.AZURE_APIM_APPSERVICEURL }}" --specification-path "${{ env.API_IMPORT_SPECIFICATION_PATH }}" --specification-format OpenApi --subscription-required false
    - name: logout
      run: >
        az logout
```